# Disable keycode printing in urxvt

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, urxvt, rxvt

When I press `alt + left arrow`, Urxvt prints `[D`, or `alt + up arrow` prints `[A`.

Is there a way to disable this behavior so that urxvt just does nothing?

Answer (score 2):

These can be configured in `~/.Xresources` file. Urxvt has `Urxvt*keysym` options to remap keycodes (see [Urxvt man page)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/urxvt) For example:

```
Urxvt*keysym.A-Left: command:\000
Urxvt*keysym.A-Right: command:\000
```

This will remap <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to nothing.

You need to remember to do `xrdb ~/.Xresources` in order to this work, and spawn a new Urxvt terminal.

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is that urxvt is translating the key chord <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> into the escape sequence `\e\e[D` (I use `\e` to represent an escape character). This is a reasonable choice; another common one is `\eO1D`.

You should configure the applications running in the terminal to understand that `\e\e[D` means <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>. For bash and other applications using the readline library, add a line like this in your `~/.inputrc` (in this example, I make the key combination move backward word by word):

```
"\e\e[D": backward-word
```

Alternatively, configure rxvt to send `\eO1D` (and if necessary teach your applications to understand this as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>). This might be more convenient than `\e\e[D` because it doesn't have two control characters in a row. You can configure rxvt's key bindings through [X resources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_resources). Put the following line in your `~/.Xresources` (many environments load it when you log in; to load the file manually, run `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`):

```
URxvt.keysym.Meta-Left: \033O1D
```